# Determine whether f is one-to-one and/or onto.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Define $$f: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$$by$$f(x,y)=(2x+2y,x-y)$$ Determine whether $f$ is one-to-one and/or onto. Explain why.

I know how solve if it's like: 
$$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$$defined by$$f(x,y)=(x+y,x)$$

But I'm lost when it comes to this one.
Please help and explain why.

Comment: What's such a big difference between the one you ask about and the one you know how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$f$ is one-to-one if and only if $\det f\neq 0$.

Comment: 1-1 and onto, in fact, which OP asks about

Comment: @BrianO http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200774/question-on-finite-vector-spaces-injective-surjective-and-if-v-is-not-finite

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, not true for infinite-dimensional spaces. More precisely, then, a linear transformation $f\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ is 1-1 and onto *iff* its matrix is invertible. & similarly for other fields. And here, dim = 2.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is the linear transformation whose matrix is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
&2 &2 \tag{$M_f$}\\
&1 &-1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which, as is easily seen, is invertible. (For example, the determinant of $M_f$ is $-4$, and a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is nonzero.)

A linear transformation is invertible iff its matrix is invertible. So $f$ has a (two-sided) inverse function $f^{-1}$, satisfying $f \circ f^{-1} = f^{-1}\circ f = \mathrm{id}$ (where $\mathrm{id}(\vec{x}) = \vec{x}$, for all $\vec{x}\in \Bbb R^2$) and therefore (why?) it's a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y)=(2x+2y,x-y)=(0,0) \Rightarrow 2x+2y=0 , x-y=0 \Rightarrow x=y=0$$ thus $f$ is injective, by using $\ker f+\text{im } f=\dim v$ it is obvious $f$ is bijective.